# Does Rails have a built-in authentication system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, restful-authentication

I have implemented authentication systems for webapps several times over the years, but before I do it once more, I thought I'd ask if there's a canned solution I should know about.

Last time I checked, there was no built-in Rails authentication system and the standard solution was the [restful-authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master) plugin. Is that still the case? Or perhaps it's been folded into Rails itself by now? I've seen that happen.

Comment: Unlikely that restful-authentication will be folded in as there are so many different ways to authenticate that it is actually a good thing that it is a 'plugin'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restful-authentication is still the standard. If you haven't look at the plugin for a while, the source has moved to [Github](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master)

Answer (score 6):

I'd now suggest [AuthLogic](http://www.railsinside.com/plugins/145-authlogic-another-take-on-rails-authentication.html) instead of restful-auth, it is far less intrusive but less supported (restful-auth is included in things like [bort](http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application/)).

Comment: I second using AuthLogic, benefits are that it is a gem instead of a plugin, that means you don't have to maintain the code unless you want to. RA uses generators, which make it your responsibility to add in new updates. Security fix for AuthLogic? Just run gem update!